# No module named flask_script

Tags: ubuntu, flask

I am trying to run a program that requires flask_script. Flask is installed both on my machine and in a virtual environment.  I cannot get my machine or the virtual environment to find flask_script.  Please advise.  Running Ubuntu.

Comment: Hi Steve Scott, and welcome to Stack Overflow. You say that you've tried, but failed, to get either your machine or virtual environment to find flask_script; could you [edit] your question to describe what you've tried so far and how that is working or failing?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have you actually installed Flask-Script?

If not, try `pip install Flask-Script`.

Comment: Thanks!  I thought flask-script was a part of flask, but apparently it is a separate package.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install 'Flask Script Extras' package by running the command

```sh
pip install flask_script_extras
```